# Tools of the trade

Tags: medieval

In my game there is a group of people known as 'The Beast Masters'  who's primary role is to keep magical beasts out of the town and away from the main entrances. This is so the people living there can come and go as they please relatively safely.

The common beasts range from mouse sized pests, to 12 feet tall  terrors.

Some beasts also have magical abilities which include fire breath, toxic slime saliva, ice breath, and super strength.

The story is set in a medieval fantasy world where most magic has been outlawed.

What tools would they require to keep the beasts at bay?

So far I have given them elemental shields, dog catcher poles, canons and some other big weapons.

Another role they have is capturing the beasts so they can be used for their abilities.

Edit 1: The Beast Masters themselves have no powers or special abilities, but they have a vast knowledge of their behaviors.

Edit 2: the surrounding area is mostly cleared forest bearing stumps, and scattered with paths and roads for about half a mile.

After that it is mostly woodland forest, cave, and rivers.

Comment: Well .. presumably they can "master" beasts through their powers, so why do they need all those weapons and what not? What are the limits of their abilities? If they _don't_ have abilities then they're just ... hunters? Animal Control?

Comment: @AndreiROM I think he meant the beasts have these powers.

Comment: @ross - i totally get that. It's just that the term "beast masters" triggers some connotations from other novels and video games. In those stories beast masters are typically able to form some sort of psychic connection with animals and control them, speak to them, befriend them, etc. I'm trying to understand of this is the case here, or if these folks are essentially just hunters.

Comment: So how big is this "lorry", she a giant?

Comment: Are you considering fortifications as separate from this topic?

Comment: I've made my post a bit clearer. Thanks for the questions.

Comment: Different tools for different monsters. Can't tell without knowing ecosystem near your city.

Answer (score 2):

So this is basically a beast master guild, where students come in and learn the trade of beast mastering, starting as an apprentice, and working up to master.

As such each would be schooled in all beasts; anatomy, weaknesses, fears, what traps work, what bait works, etc.

As to tools, this could be as varied as the beasts you have, so it's not really something that can be answered, BUT as you state in your question, one tool they would have is the beasts themselves.

You start by digging pit traps all around a settlement, and capture beasts alive. Start working on domestication through the usual methods like breeding for tameness. Once you have tame beasts then their powers are yours to use, so you go out and capture more beasts. Eventually over many years you build up a vast store of knowledge and a menagerie of powerful creatures, and then when a gobalfez attacks the village you know that its armor is thinnest behind its ears and it has a weakness to electricity. So you mount your electric land eel, grab your lance, call up your pack of lightning floofs, and ride out to kill the beast before it can eat anyone else.

Comment: Lighting floofs are fierce creatures. +1 for taming them.

Comment: @AndreiROM Despite its ferocity, the lightning floof which is a pack hunter is much easier to domesticate than the graul, which is a solo hunter that shuns others of its kind (except for breeding). This is because the pack mentality defines a strong sense of Us and Them, and a BM that is able to become an Us will be able do a lot with even newly captured floofs. That does not mean that you should let your guard down. Floofs despise weakness, and even ones that have been tame for several generations will attack another floof that it sees as weak. Many a crispy BM learned not to go to work sick.

Comment: @andyd273 - well done, sir